# JPA - close EntityManagerFactory raises Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, derby

I am currently developing a small application with an in memory derby database. I am using Hibernate 4.3.10 and JPA 2. Here is the link to my small demo application: http://1drv.ms/1KfCiHK

This short code results in "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active."

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(null);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = cb.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
em.createQuery(query.select(query.from(MyEntity.class))).getResultList();

em.close();
emf.close(); // Here the exception is raised!
```

So, even if I do not need any transaction and did not start one, something started one?!

<del>If I replace the three query lines with this</del>

<del>em.createQuery("select m from MyEntity m", MyEntity.class).getResultList();</del>

<del>then there is no exeption raised, although it is doing the same!</del>

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: I have tested your example and I got Error "Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active"  for both JPQL and CriteriaQuery.

Comment: Mhh, you are right, I must be blind or something... well nevertheless my question remains: Why is the exception raised? I do not started a transaction. Also `em.getTransaction().isActive()` returns **false**. So, where is my fault? Or is it a bug somewhere in Hibernate/Derby?

Answer (score 0):

You need the name of the persistence unit, the name is in the persistence.xml file.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("name of the persistence unit");
```

Comment: That is not making any difference, as long as you only have one persistence unit.